# Is there a built in way to get the country name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, location

Creating a weather app. Using Apixu. If I can get the country name, the user doesn't have to provide it. So I want the program to fetch the default system country in a manner we use the `Time` class for fetching the system time.

I don't want to use geolocation. Also `TZInfo` isn't what I am looking for. I need a built-in way to get the country name (may be from time zone?).

Comment: "I don't want to use geolocation." - then asking the user is your only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you cannot get the country name from a time instance because time zones do not map to countries.

However, from a time instance, you can get the time zone, and by using `Time.new`, you can access the current system time.

```
Time.new.zone
# => "JST"
```

Comment: Time.now.zone will also give you the same result.